How to use a SwiftUI view as a UITableView header view?
I am currently using a UIViewRepresentable to display a UITableView so I don't have access to the view property of a traditional UIViewController.
I am trying to have a banner as the header view where the SwiftUI Color blue stretches the full width and takes about 200 points as height. I am just getting an empty view.
Furthermore, in this example I am using Color.blue. But in reality, I want the height of the header view to be exactly of whatever is in the SwiftUI view without any padding so is there a way to pass the height to the header view?
func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITableView {
        let tableView = UITableView()
        tableView.delegate = context.coordinator
        tableView.dataSource = context.coordinator
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        
        let vc = UIHostingController(rootView: Color.blue.frame(height: 200))
        let headerView = UIViewType(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.width, height: 200))
        headerView.addSubview(vc.view)
        headerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        tableView.addSubview(headerView)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            headerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableView.widthAnchor),
            headerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableView.topAnchor),
            headerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200)
        ])
        
        tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView
        
        return tableView
    }

